# SoX play sound at full volume regardless of mute or current system volume level

Tags: alsa, sox

I need to script playing a sound.  Think https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cl0EI44nMXE&t=37s

The catch is I need it to play regardless of if the system is muted or the sound is turned low, and allow executing the command repeatedly/quickly.

An acceptable solution could save, play, and restore volume irrespective of *other* system events - but it needs to work if the command is executed multiple times overlapping itself.  Eg:

```
@time=0             @time=[after]
vol=10%             volume=10% preserved
V                   v
   |--no--|    
       |--no--|
        |--no--| ...
```

my system is ubuntu20.04, using `alsa`.  Bash shell would be preferred if the result is understandable for `mere humans`; else perhaps python? For reference, the following work as expected on their own (and installing programs available in normal repos is OK).

```
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master 20%+ # volume increase
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master toggle # toggles mute
play no.mp3 # SoX play mp3
```